# Date formatting using Joda time library

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime

In a java class, i get the date as string say "renewDate"  from the datepicker-input form in mm/dd/yyyy.

When i try to update in the code using joda time library

```
DateTime expireDate = new DateTime(renewDate);
// i get error at above line
updateOrganization.setRenewdate(expireDate.toDate());
organizationDAO.update(updateOrganization);
```

but if i format the date in the form i.e, from mm/dd/yyyy to  yyyy-mm-dd and send it to the java class its working fine.

How can i format the date from mm/dd/yy to yyyy-mm-dd at Java class. Input is Stringformat.

Comment: What type of datepicker? AWT,SWT,JSF,JS ... ?

Comment: Try looking through datepickers API for keywords like 'pattern'.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The list of valid formats for the constructor you are using are detailed in the [javadoc of ISODateTimeFormat](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/ISODateTimeFormat.html#dateTimeParser%28%29), which does not include "mm/dd/yyyy":

> datetime          = time | date-opt-time
>    time              = 'T' time-element [offset]
>    date-opt-time     = date-element ['T' [time-element] [offset]]
>    date-element      = std-date-element | ord-date-element | week-date-element
>    std-date-element  = yyyy ['-' MM ['-' dd]]
>    ord-date-element  = yyyy ['-' DDD]
>    week-date-element = xxxx '-W' ww ['-' e]
>    time-element      = HH [minute-element] | [fraction]
>    minute-element    = ':' mm [second-element] | [fraction]
>    second-element    = ':' ss [fraction]
>    fraction          = ('.' | ',') digit+
>    offset            = 'Z' | (('+' | '-') HH [':' mm [':' ss [('.' | ',') SSS]]])

You can parse a different format with a [DateTimeFormatter](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) (note MM in upper case for month):

```
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MM/dd/yyyy");
DateTime expireDate = fmt.parseDateTime(renewDate);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to parse the date using the static method [parse](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#parse%28java.lang.String,%20org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter%29) as the constructor assumes the String is in the ISO format

The date format you need is as below

```
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MM/dd/yyyy");
DateTime expireDate = DateTime.parse( renewDate, fmt );
```